# why travis-ci on scala project runs rake?

Tags: scala, sbt, travis-ci

I see this in `travis-ci` documentation:

> Projects using sbt #
>
> If your project has project directory or build.sbt file in the
>   repository root, the Travis CI Scala builder will use sbt to build it.

so as I understand this I don't need `travis.yaml`

So how come [testbuildsbt project](https://github.com/avidanyum/testbuildsbt/tree/master) fails [on travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/avidanyum/testbuildsbt)? I see its not running even `sbt` its running only rake.  (note the link to travis ci shows its logs)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note the part **the Travis CI Scala builder**. This assumes you're in a situation where Travis using the Scala builder in the first place. And to get that, you need a `.travis.yml` file with at least:

```
language: scala
```

When the language is Scala, sbt will be recognized if you have `build.sbt` or `project/`. Otherwise, it will look for `pom.xml`, `build.gradle`, etc.

My advice is to *always* have a `.travis.yml` file, otherwise, you're dependent on a lot of "guessing" happening from Travis. The bare minimal for a Scala project, IMO, is:

```
sudo: false # container-based infrastructure
language: scala
scala: 2.11.7
jdk: oraclejdk8
```